# Reading key/value parameters from a file into a shell script

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I've got my script working almost. The goal of this is to take defined values from a file and then populate these valeus in a shell script at runtime.

Please take a look at what i have here...

The first file: ab.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_TYPE=$1 #IDENTIFY USER TYPE TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3,TYPE4
USERNAME=$2
PERMISSION_TYPE=$3 #IDENTIFY PERMISSION TYPE SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT
TARGET_USER=$4
TARGET_TABLE=$5

if [ $USER_TYPE == 'TYPE1' ]
        then
cat Parameters.conf |while read USERNAME
do
sqlplus / as sysdba <<  E00
CREATE USER ${USERNAME}
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER ${USERNAME} DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO ${USERNAME};
GRANT CONNECT TO ${USERNAME};
exit
E00
done

cat p.conf |while read PERMISSION_TYPE TARGET_SCHEMA TARGET_TABLE USERNAME
do
sqlplus / as sysdba > /home/o/output/output.log << E01
GRANT ${PERMISSION_TYPE} ON ${TARGET_USER}.${TARGET_TABLE} TO ${USERNAME};
E01
done
fi
```

This is the file Parameters.conf where the values are defined and should come from...

Parameters.conf

```
USER_TYPE TYPE1
USERNAME NEWUSER
PERMISSION_TYPE SELECT,UPDATE
TARGET_USER TESTUSER
TARGET_TABLE ABC
```

Comment: Don't use all-caps names for your own variables -- this makes them conflict with environment variables defined by the operating system and the shell, which are restricted to that namespace (for instance, there's a `USER` preset in bash which you've overriding here). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, for POSIX conventions around environment variable names (and by extension shell variable names, since they share a namespace).

Comment: The USER variable I actually don't use in my script. Whoops

Comment: Sure; that said, the point was more about convention -- if you were using `user` or `username` as opposed to `USER` or `USERNAME`, you wouldn't need to be policing which specific variables your OS or shell is or isn't setting and whether there's a conflict.

Comment: ...btw, which version of bash is this going to be run with? As of 4.0, there's associative array functionality available, so we can keep variables read from the file in a completely different namespace from shell variables. That same effect could be done with, say, prefixing or suffixing if compatibility with other versions is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First choice: Associative array

This requires bash 4.0 or newer to support `declare -A`; see below for other options.

```
#!/bin/bash

# first, read your key/value pairs into shell variables
declare -A v=( )
while read -r var value; do
  v[$var]=$value
done < Parameters.conf

# second, perform a command that depends on them
sqlplus / as sysdba <<  E00
CREATE USER ${v[USERNAME]}
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER ${v[USERNAME]} DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO ${v[USERNAME]};
GRANT CONNECT TO ${v[USERNAME]};
exit
E00

sqlplus / as sysdba > /home/o/output/output.log << E01
GRANT ${v[PERMISSION_TYPE]} ON ${v[TARGET_USER]}.${v[TARGET_TABLE]} TO ${v[USERNAME]};
E01
```

---

Key points:

- Assignment to a shell variable *which is itself named in a variable* is described in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables); likewise for associative arrays.
- The redirection needs to be done as `while read key value; do ...; done <input` rather than `cat input | while read key value; do ...; done` to avoid the bug [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- The actual `sqlplus` calls shouldn't be inside the loop, because the loop body is run once per line in the file. Since you want *all* the file's lines to be read (and all the variables assigned) *before* running `sqlplus`, the loop should entirely complete before `sqlplus` is called.
- Using either a prefix or an associative-array ensures that variables coming from the configuration file can't override system environment variables like `PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD`.

---

#### Second choice: Prefixed namespace

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r var value; do
  printf -v "v_$var" %s "$value"
done <Parameters.conf

# second, perform a command that depends on them
sqlplus / as sysdba <<  E00
CREATE USER ${v_USERNAME}
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER ${v_USERNAME} DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO ${v_USERNAME};
GRANT CONNECT TO ${v_USERNAME};
exit
E00

sqlplus / as sysdba > /home/o/output/output.log << E01
GRANT ${v_PERMISSION_TYPE} ON ${v_TARGET_USER}.${v_TARGET_TABLE} TO ${v_USERNAME};
E01
```

Comment: so it'll be:  while read Parameter1 parameter2 so-on and so forth

Comment: and then at the very end I'll do done < Parameters.conf?

Comment: Quite correct. You might make it `while read -r parameter1 parameter2 ...` to avoid `read`'s default behavior of parsing (and thus deleting) backslashes in input. (Even if you don't *expect* backslashes, it typically makes sense to turn off that behavior unless you explicitly have a reason to want it).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so appreciative for this. I understand it now completely!

Comment: Glad to help! And do accept my apologies for not paying enough attention earlier. (I've also amended to try to show two different approaches to separating configuration variables from others -- associative arrays, which other languages might call "hashes" or "maps"; and using a prefixed namespace).