# Bash get string value

Tags: bash

I have to get the hostname for a network device out of its config file. The file looks like:

```
...
hostname=T14Z18
ipaddress=192.168.0.1
...
```

How does one do that? I am ssh'ing into the machine.

Comment: BTW, this is potentially very much related to [Reading key/value parameters from a file into a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964946/reading-key-value-parameters-from-a-file-into-a-shell-script) -- the only difference being that the answers there typically read the *whole* file, whereas here you're trying to extract just a single item. If you plan to read more than just a few items, it'll probably be much more efficient to go with a single-pass approach, as in the answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` and `cut` like that:

```
$ grep '^hostname=' configfile  | cut -d= -f2
T14Z18
```

You can also combine the above with `ssh` command in `Bash`:

```
$ ssh "$(grep '^hostname=' configfile | cut -d= -f2)"
```

Everything between `$(` and `)` will be replaced by the output of the command inside the parenthesis so it would be the same as if you typed `ssh T14Z18` manually.
This feature is called [command
substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
in `Bash`.

Also notice that `OpenSSH` that you probably use has its own config
stored in `~/.ssh/config` that you can use to create aliases.  For
example, the following entry creates an alias called `rpi`:

```
Host rpi
User pi
Hostname 192.168.1.161
```

You can now just do `ssh rpi` and user and hostname will be found
automatically by `OpenSSH` client. You can of course use a hostname such as T14Z18 is in your example instead of IP address if you have `DNS` server in your network.

Comment: Better to quote that: `ssh "$(grep '^hostname=' configfile | cut -d= -f2)"` -- that way if you don't get exactly one word out, the error message will make sense (rather than additional words being treated as parts of a command to send to the remote machine, or 0-words passing the first subsequent argument to ssh as the hostname).

Answer (score 3):

With simple **`awk`** command:

```
awk -F'=' '$1 == "hostname"{ print $2; exit }' configfile
```

Comment: More efficient than `grep | cut`, and also has the effect of `head -n 1`, preventing multiple matches.

Answer (score 2):

With [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu)-[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) if `-P` [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) regex *switch* is implemented :

```
grep -oP 'hostname=\K.*' configfile
                   __
                    ^
                    |
```

[image] *restart the match* trick

[Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex)

Comment: Should probably specify "with GNU `grep`, when compiled with optional PCRE support" to be a little more up-front about the portability constraints.

Comment: Post edited. It's not PCRE but perl regex to be more precise

Comment: PCRE == "Perl-Compatible Regex Engine". Compiling `grep` with such support links in the 3rd-party library in libpcre at compile time, so I believe describing it as "PCRE" is entirely appropriate here.

Comment: The `man grep` is not _that_ clear, it says _perl regex_ and PCRE, that is not the same

Comment: `grep -P` is implemented by `pcresearch.c` in the codebase. See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/pcresearch.c for the source. It's *absolutely* PCRE.

Comment: You are picky, thanks for your search ;) I wouldn't wrote in `man grep` _perl regex_, but _PCRE regex_, though. What I meant, is that PCRE is a subset of perl's regex