# How to create a dictionary from a text file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary in bash from a text file which looks like this:

```
H96400275|A
H96400276|B
H96400265|C
H96400286|D
```

Basically I want a dictionary like this from this file `file.txt`:

```
KEYS        VALUES
H96400275 = A
H96400276 = B
H96400265 = C
H96400286 = D
```

I created following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a dictionary

while read line; do 

  key=$(echo $line | cut -d "|" -f1)
  data=$(echo $line | cut -d "|" -f2)
  dictionary[$key]="$data"
done < file.txt


echo ${dictionary[H96400275]}
```

However, this does not print `A`, rather it prints `D`. Can you please help ?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964946/reading-key-value-parameters-from-a-file-into-a-shell-script

Comment: Don't create an additional subshell for each call to `cut` simply use *parameter expansions* `key="${line%|*}"` and `data="${line#*|}"`, or just `dictionary[${line%|*}]=${line#*|}` (after fixing the `-a` to `-A` problem)

Comment: There is more than one remark on this post! Please consider [smart oguz ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58928414/1765658)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the only problem is that you have to use -A instead of -a

```
      -a     Each name is an indexed array variable (see Arrays above).
      -A     Each name is an **associative** array variable (see Arrays above).
```

Answer (score 8):

Associative arrays (*dictionaries* in your terms) are declared using `-A`, not `-a`. For references to indexed (ones declared with `-a`) arrays' elements, bash performs arithmetic expansion on the subscript (`$key` and `H96400275` in this case); so you're basically overwriting `dictionary[0]` over and over, and then asking for its value; thus `D` is printed.

And to make this script more effective, you can use `read` in conjunction with a custom `IFS` to avoid `cut`s. E.g:

```
declare -A dict

while IFS='|' read -r key value; do
    dict[$key]=$value
done < file

echo "${dict[H96400275]}"
```

---

See [Bash Reference Manual § 6.7 Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays).

Comment: That's another good way to avoid to subshells associated with calling `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is so named associative array. And to declare it you need to use command:

```
declare -A dictionary
```